# how to join one row in using the comma in python?

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe

I have created a dataframe like this. My purpose is go join the character of each row of dataframe, like '10,0' for the first row. How can I do that? Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10,20),'b': range(0,10)})

>>df
    a  b
0  10  0
1  11  1
2  12  2
3  13  3
4  14  4
5  15  5
6  16  6
7  17  7
8  18  8
9  19  9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10,20),'b': range(0,10)})
valueList = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    valueList.append(str(df['a'][i]) + "," + str(df['b'][i]))
print valueList
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
['10,0', '11,1', '12,2', '13,3', '14,4', '15,5', '16,6', '17,7', '18,8', '19,9']
```

or simply :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10,20),'b': range(0,10)})

print [",".join(map(str, pairs)) for pairs in zip(df['a'],df['b'])]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
['10,0', '11,1', '12,2', '13,3', '14,4', '15,5', '16,6', '17,7', '18,8', '19,9']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Uses List Comprehension to return list.

```
[ str(x[0]) + "," + str(x[1]) for x in df.values.tolist()]

['10,0',
 '11,1',
 '12,2',
 '13,3',
 '14,4',
 '15,5',
 '16,6',
 '17,7',
 '18,8',
 '19,9']
```